# How to name labels in russian for bottleneck retraining?

Tags: tensorflow, label, image-recognition

I am retraining an inception v3 and mobilenet models on flower categories according to [`tensorflow-for-poets-2`](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/#0) codelab. However, right now there is a need for naming labels (corresponding folders of images) in Russian.

Is it possible?
If yes, what kind of setting should I do?

BTW, I have checked the possibility of retraining in Russian with folder names `роза1`  and `роза2`. So, surprisingly, it had worked correctly, giving appropriate predictions after retraining. On the other hand, when I have retrained model on folder names as `роза`, `тюльпан` it raised an error:

> INFO:tensorflow:Looking for images in 'роза' INFO:tensorflow:Looking
>   for images in 'тюльпан' ERROR:tensorflow:Only one valid folder of
>   images found at tf_files/flower_photos - multiple classes are needed
>   for classification.

Any advice is appreciated!